# Apply wait for button change to text and again text change to button in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I'm working on application that on **[RUN]** button click will change text to i.e **[QUEUE]**.

After page refresh, button will have text i.e **[RUNNING]**. Again after refresh page, button will have text **[VIEW]**. Waiting time is dynamic and can vary.

User should see update through page refresh.

**[RUN] --> QUEUE --> RUNNING --> [VIEW]**.

I have following code:

```
for(int i=1; i<11; i++) {
        String fileNames=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+ i +"]/td[1]")).getText();
        System.out.println("file names: " +fileNames);
        
        if(fileNames.equalsIgnoreCase("AlgeriaTest005")) {
            String colText=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+ i +"]/td[3]")).getText();
            
            if(colText.equalsIgnoreCase("RUN")) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+ i +"]/td[3]/button[1]")).click();
                
                WebElement dropDown=driver.findElement(By.xpath(" /html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/select"));
                Select select=new Select(dropDown);
                select.selectByVisibleText("NoReinsurance");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/button[1]")).click();
                //js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", showEle);   //it will scroll again..
                
                String colText2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+ i +"]/td[3]")).getText();
                
                if(colText2.equalsIgnoreCase("QUEUE")) {
                    System.out.println("File is changed to Queue..");
                    
                    driver.navigate().refresh();
                    wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMinutes(1));
                    //driver.navigate().refresh();
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement( driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+ i +"]/td[3]")), "RUNNING"));
                    
                    driver.navigate().refresh();
                    String colText3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+ i +"]/td[3]")).getText();
                    
                    if(colText3.equalsIgnoreCase("RUNNING")) {
                        
                        System.out.println("File is changed to Running..");
                        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMinutes(5));
                        driver.navigate().refresh();
                        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(
                              driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+ i +"]/td[3]/button[1]")), "VIEW"));
                        
                        driver.navigate().refresh();
                        System.out.println("File is changed to view");
                        break;
                    }
                    else 
                        System.out.println("file is not changed to Running.."); Assert.assertTrue(false);
                    
                }
                else 
                    System.out.println("file is not changed to Queue.."); Assert.assertTrue(false);
                    
                
            }
            else if(colText.equalsIgnoreCase("Damage file not available ")) {
                System.out.println("file is damaged..");
                Assert.assertTrue(false);
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your code first clicks "RUN" and then expects "QUEUE" and other states. I would move `if(colText2.equalsIgnoreCase("QUEUE")) {` and other if statements to same level as `if(colText.equalsIgnoreCase("RUN")) {`. This would make if blocks sorter and easier to understand. It will also work in cases where system is so fast that QUEUED state is skipped.

Comment: yeah, some times, it will taking more time than specified time. then it throwing TimeOut exception. I don't know, how to handle this.

Comment: Timeout exception sounds like task is taking longer than you have reserved time. What line gives that exception?